# Чего не срабатывает смена фона gwt?

Tags: java, gwt

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wrapper HTML for App</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MySampleApplication.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
            src="MySampleApplication/MySampleApplication.nocache.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="my-div" ></div>
<h1>Sample Application</h1>

<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td id="slot1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

body, td, a, div, .p {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif
}

.my-red-class { background-color: #ff0000 }
```

---

```
package com.mySampleApplication.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.*;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>
 */
public class MySampleApplication implements EntryPoint {

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {
         Button button = new Button("Click me");
        RootPanel.get("slot1").add(button);

        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
               Element element = Document.get().getElementById("my-div");
               element.toggleClassName("my-red");
            }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, прекратите дублировать один и тот же по сути вопрос.

Comment: извините действительно не хочет работать не могу понять в чем тут ошибка

Comment: в CSS у вас `.my-red-class` ,а в коде `"my-red"`

Comment: Ну и div ваш сделайте непустым, иначе вы его не увидите.

Comment: В каком смысле не пустым?

Comment: Текст в него, например, добавьте.

Comment: <div id=my-div ></div>? или еще что то дописать тут нужно?

Comment: <div id="my-div">Hello world</div>

Comment: Советую проделать все то же для начала на голом HTML + JS.

Comment: понял так и сделаю